# Error al conectar un programa con una base de datos Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-11g

Estoy tratando de conectar un programa de Java con una base de datos hecha en SQLPlus de Oracle 11g, en un principio la conexión funcionaba pero luego me salio el siguiente error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:678)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at connection.ConexionOracle.conectar(ConexionOracle.java:31)
    at connection.ConexionOracle.consult(ConexionOracle.java:73)
    at connection.ConexionOracle.getColumn(ConexionOracle.java:60)
    at view.JpanelCreate.<init>(JpanelCreate.java:35)
    at view.JpanelCRUD.<init>(JpanelCRUD.java:28)
    at view.JFrameMainWindow.<init>(JFrameMainWindow.java:18)
    at controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:13)
    at test.Runner.main(Runner.java:7)
```

El código donde conecto el programa con la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
public ConexionOracle() {
    user = "usuario";
    pass = "123";
}    

public ConexionOracle conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            String BaseDeDatos = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(BaseDeDatos, user,pass);            
            if (conexion != null) {
                System.out.println("Conexion exitosa!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Conexion fallida!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
        return this;
    }
```

¿Qué puede estar fallando? ¿El fallo es en el programa, en Oracle o en otra cosa externa?

Al revisar los archivos listener.ora y tnsnames.ora aparece esto:

tnsnames.ora

```
    # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
      (SID = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

*actualizacion*

Después de revisar varios foros y probar varias cosas, el problema se convirtió en lo siguiente:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:678)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229
```

Comment: ¿Podría ser que la base de datos no este levantada? ¿Te fijaste si el puerto 1521 esta habilitado y escuchando peticiones?

Comment: Me parece que le faltan datos a tu cadena de conexión. Imagino que instalaste la versión JDBC Thin, por lo que dice aquí: `String BaseDeDatos = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";`.... si es así, [observa en la documentación cómo se construye la conexión](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcthin.htm). No veo dónde le pasas las credenciales, como usuario, contraseña, etc.

Comment: ya revise el puerto y si se encuentra habilitado, la base de datos tambien se encuentra funcional, respecto a la cadena de conexion, los datos de usuario y contraseña tambien se agregaron aqui: `conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(BaseDeDatos, user,pass);`, al medio dia funcionaba correctamente la aplicacion, sin embargo, al cambiar de red, dejo de funcionar